# How to add more hard drives to my ubuntu home server

Tags: server, hard-drive, webserver, websites, hosting

I have a home server with ubuntu  server installed. I am hosting my site of it on the same hard drive. I was wondering could I add another hard drive to my server, so I can move the website to that hard drive. And could I split up the hard drives let's saying have one hard drives for users and another for the website... I would not mind any suggestions thank you

Comment: From the Ubuntu Server perspective, this is easy. You simply edit /etc/fstab to reflect the new storage devices, and mount them anywhere convenient upon your filesystem. Don't be hasty with your plan.

Answer (score 0):

Yes adding hard drives is a fairly simple process as long as you don't need raid or other advanced functionality. The simplest way is to boot into a live disk of GParted to partition the drive (Doable through command line but more difficult, skip this if you've already formatted and partitioned the drive). Then you can mount the drive on the server by adding it to the fstab (/etc/fstab). `sudo lshw -C disk` should give you the logical name of installed drives if the drives are the same then run this before and after adding the new drive. Once you know which one is the new drive take the logical name (eg. /dev/sdb) and add it to the fstab in this format (Mountpoint is a folder where the new drive will be accessible) `/dev/logicalname  /mountpoint  filesystem defaults  0  2`

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive might help to provide a more detailed explanation.